# 2 divs next to each other goes into next div

Tags: html, css

So, I have a problem, I can't seem to find a solution. I know that this is something ridiculously easy, but I'm still a noob...

Whenever I use command `float:left`, these 2 `.con-icon` and `#con-info` runs across to next div called `#test` (the one in color dark red). But I need them to stay within `#contain` borders.

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/3eoj06b3/.

```
<section id="contain">
    <h1>Contain</h1>
    <div id="con-info">
        <div class="con-icon">
            <h2>1</h2>
            <h2>1</h2>
            <h2>1</h2>
        </div>
        <p>2</p>
        <p>2</p>
        <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="test"></div>
</section>
```

CSS is in the link

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you want it to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#con-info:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some info about how this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `overflow:auto;` line to your `#con-info` class. http://jsfiddle.net/garsdubh/. This will make your parent element aware of its floated children heights.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow: hidden` on `#con-info`. Since you have declared `height: auto` for `#con-info` you need to hide the `overflow` as well to have automatic height.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/3eoj06b3/4/)**

```
#con-info {
    overflow: hidden; /* This is added to your Fiddle */
    position:relative;
    border:2px solid #C60;
    width:40%;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:10%;
}
```